# how to show last two node in xslt?

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

could you please help me getting last two node in xslt .here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsJ/1

**expectoutput**

```
<h1>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with
      root element of XSL-FO. Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF
   </h1>
   <h1>Added some links to useful XSLT sites</h1>
```

**xslt code**

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
      <hmtl>
        <head>
          <title>New Version!</title>
        </head>
        <xsl:for-each select="ul/li[last() &gt;2]">
            <h1><xsl:value-of select="."/></h1>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </hmtl>
    </xsl:template>
```

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <ul>
        <li>A new XSLT engine is added: Saxon 9.5 EE, with a license (thank you Michael Kay!)</li>
        <li>XSLT 3.0 support when using the new Saxon 9.5 EE engine!</li>
        <li>Preview your result as HTML when doctype is set to HTML (see this example)</li>
        <li>Preview your result as PDF when doctype is set to XML and your document starts with root element of XSL-FO. Apache FOP is used to generate the PDF</li>
        <li>Added some links to useful XSLT sites</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short but effective: `ul/li[position() &gt;= last()-1]`

Position of current processed node must be greater or equal than the index of last element minus 1.

Shown on: http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsJ/2

Answer (score 0):

You can use below `XPath` expression:

```
/ul/li[position()>count(/ul/li)-2]
```